# What RPC method / CLI command to use to query validators' vote account Authorized Withdrawer addresses

Tags: validator

I would like to run a query to get validators' vote account Authorized Withdrawer addresses. What RPC method and/or CLI command to use for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `vote-account` command on the CLI:

```
$ solana -um vote-account CMPo7H14cu4irHQgBo5uDLgsrXX6TfVaMmqeo4T2A3BG
Account Balance: 6.488355923 SOL
Validator Identity: HuVuiJmd5155rPM7yKmDkVPBYPCiJTMw1MD8Hx6PBwok
Vote Authority: {439: "HuVuiJmd5155rPM7yKmDkVPBYPCiJTMw1MD8Hx6PBwok"}
Withdraw Authority: DbnGB4k6GALXSi7nKBNGyQwHsbjk5nc3PJrZNFJ59PE3
Credits: 15392149
Commission: 10%
... and much more information
```

Under the hood, this is just fetching the account with `getAccountInfo` and parsing the account data as a vote state. Here's the helper function in the CLI doing just that: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e5490b8d0906eed87dfc08f326ee6a02db3d7c58/cli/src/vote.rs#L1173